# how to update iptables-persistent?

Tags: networking, security, iptables, blacklist, fail2ban

After installing `iptables-persistent` I see:

```
ubuntu@dur:~$ 
ubuntu@dur:~$ cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed Jan 11 14:36:17 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [251:16508]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [225:57304]
:f2b-ASTERISK - [0:0]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j f2b-ASTERISK
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -s 67.212.84.21/32 -j DROP
-A f2b-ASTERISK -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jan 11 14:36:17 2017
ubuntu@dur:~$
```

Can I add to this file so that I can block certain IP's even after reboot?  Yes, I'm running `fail2ban`.  This is on Amazon, for what it's worth, running Asterisk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I managed to persist across reboots with `Fail2Ban` & `netfilter-persistent`

With your active `action.d` config add to `actionban` and `actionunban` as follows ...

```
...
# Add/Remove newly updated rule to file and remove dupes
iptables-save | uniq | awk '!seen[$0]++' > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
# Import updated config
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
# Save config for reboots
netfilter-persistent save
# Now refresh the persistent daemon
netfilter-persistent reload
...
```

This will capture newly added ip's and if you manually `unban` an ip

Comment: Even with sudo, I get the `permission denied` error on `sudo iptables-save | uniq | awk '!seen[$0]++' > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`. How do I fix it?